# How to receive and store file on tcp socket for chome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome app which should accept a file from client and store in local file system. I have a tcp server where client needs to connect and send file. I have listener for tcp socket where I listen for messages. Now client streams a file of certain length that is already known. How to get that file and store.

TCP Server:

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(socketinfo){
    tcpServerSocketId=socketinfo.socketId;
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(tcpServerSocketId, ip, 0, function (resultCode){
        if(resultCode<0)
            console.log("tcp server not connected");
        chrome.sockets.tcpServer.getInfo(tcpServerSocketId, function(info){
            tcpServerPort=info.localPort;
            sendHub("ConnectToMe "+username+" "+ip+":"+tcpServerPort);
        });
        chrome.sockets.tcpServer.onAccept.addListener(onAccept);
    });
});
```

TCP Listener:

```
    chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    if(info.socketId!=socketId){
        onReceivefromClient(info.socketId, info.data);
    }
    else{
          // console.log(ab2str(info.data));
          var result=ab2str(info.data).split(" ");
          if(result[0]=="$Lock")
            proceed(info.data);
    }
  // sendHub("ConnectToMe 98765432 10.147.231.130:58060");
});
```

Comment: have you checked what the `tcpServer.onAccept` listener returns?

Comment: yes, it actually returns chunks of data of the file, actually it's in binary format so I can't get the full idea. I have converted that into ArrayBuffer but now I don't know how to combine them and download the file.